# Why is area considered and not volume to find the force of a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

I am doing a project involving solenoids. I found multiple websites that say the force (in N) a solenoid exerts on a soft iron bar as it enters the coils can be given by the equation $$F=(NI)^2\mu_0A/2g^2$$ When thinking about it, a soft iron bar will conduct the magnetic field lines from the solenoid completely. [image]

Why then does the equation use A (area) and not V (volume)? I feel like using area will give the force exerted on a 2D object. If I wanted the force exerted on a 3D object (the soft iron bar) wouldn't I use volume?

*Note: I'd like to request that when someone edits a post, they triple check their spelling. Just in case.

Comment: you can think it intuitively by the fact that the lines enter across the area, and the force is related to the number of lines. Volume doesnt matter for the force the bar feels. Of course, the longer the bar, the heavier, so that same force will "push" the bar less effectively.

Comment: Yeah, $F=ma$. Anyway, that makes sense. The area is the limiting factor for the number of field lines going through the bar. The depth of the bar would not change anything. Okay

Comment: Is it using the the area from the leading edge of the bar?

Comment: It is the area of the leading edge in the analogous case where a dilectric is placed partly inside a capacitor. But I'm always wary of making such analogous arguments about ferromagnetism because it often hides obnoxious non-linearities.

Comment: @dmckee I believe you are trying to compare this to something with dielectrics and capacitors but I'm not sure what. Anyway its a straightforward question: "Does the force equation use a surface-to-surface distance for g?"

Comment: @CoilKid I do not remember under what assumption that specific equation was derived (my guess is that the cross area is constant, so it wouldn't matter). If you have a link to one of your sources I could figure it out for you

Comment: @julianfernandez I believe I have solved my first question "Why area, and not volume" but now I have the question "Does that equation use surface-to-surface distance for g?" As for the sources, I don't think they would help. I found that equation on about 7 online engineering calculators. All they say is A = Area and g = distance. I know what A is and what they mean. I can only assume they also meant g = surface-to-surface distance between solenoid and ferromagnetic material.

Comment: yes, but distance from what specific point? I am gonna try to find out and let you know.

Comment: @julianfernandez _from_ the leading edge of the soft iron bar _to_ the edge of the solenoid.

Comment: Ok thanks, because I could not find the solution for that specific problem and I do not remember  how to calculate it myself (it had been many years since I do not do calculation on electromagnetism, I do research in computational neuroscience now

Comment: I think volume is effectively taken into account with the $N$ term in the equation you show, is it not?  The more windings, $N$, the more force, right?  Each winding adds an additional magnetic field, B $\propto$ $\mu_{o}$IA, which is related to the force a solenoid can exert.

Comment: I believe this question can already be considered answered. I think that I should use A because it is the limiting factor in the number of magnetic field lines going through the iron. I appreciate your response though. :)